# Setup a reverse proxy for a Debian VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian, dns, proxy

I had created a debian virtualbox configured with network adapters `NAT` and `Host Only` by following [article](https://sudobird.medium.com/setup-nat-and-host-only-network-on-oracle-vm-virtualbox-9341d7babafe) with hostname `example` and domain `example.com`. It is working fine. I wanted to use a test domain locally through my host like `example.com`. I edited `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` with content `virtualbox_ip example.com`. All of them works fine. Now I am trying to setup a reverse proxy for services running on different ports. for example if there is a httpd container running on port 500, I want to forward its traffic to domain to test.example.com.

I tried different ways:

- Installing Nginx Proxy Manager on VitualBox and Adding Subdomain to hosts file of host machine
- Installing Nginx on Host Machine and Setting Up Proxy Manually

Both of them did not work. Is it really possible to do this. May be I am missing something or doing something wrong.

###### Extending the question along with a test example

My Windows Hosts File - Host Computer

```
192.168.56.147 example.com
```

---

Output of `ip a` in my virtualbox

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:53:55:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 86207sec preferred_lft 86207sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe53:5515/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:90:d8:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.147/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe90:d84a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

My Debian Hosts File - Virtualbox

```
127.0.1.1   example.example.com example
```

---

Installing basic packages

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install podman
```

---

Container Repositories Config

```
sudo nano /etc/containers/registries.conf
```

Replacing `# unqualified-search-registries = ["example.com"]` with `unqualified-search-registries = ["docker.io", "quay.io"]`

---

Nginx Proxy Manager

```
mkdir -p nginxproxymanager/{data,letsencrypt}
```

```
podman run -dt -p 1025:80 -p 1026:81 -p 1027:443 \
-v ./nginxproxymanager/data:/data \
-v ./nginxproxymanager/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt \
--name nginxproxymanager --restart=unless-stopped \
jc21/nginx-proxy-manager
```

---

Nginx Proxy Manager Configuration

### [image]

Attempt Failiure.

expected behaviour: test.example.com will show the same result as example.com:1026 which is nginxproxymanager itself.

[image]

I even tried pinging within the virtualmachine.

```
ping test.example.com
```

result

```
ping: test.example.com: Name or service not known
```

Comment: What is the result of the nginx proxy manager? does it only show example.com when you try go to test.example.com?

Comment: Yes, It showed only example.com.

Comment: Do you have same port as the example.com? Or it's not? As I remember I don't have that problem here. I can't guest much as you don't share more detail about it. You can share your nginx proxy manager config, the port of the container that you want to proxy, and the network topology, it will help other to figure it out. Hope an answer from you soon.

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto Thanks for your reply. I extended the question along with a test example.

Comment: I see your problem now. You can't use example.com even it's on virtualbox hosts, because the nginx proxy manager on podman, can't connect to 127.0.0.1, even the host on debian copy paste the example.com, it will refer to podman network IP, which isn't existant. You should use IP of the debian server, as the proxy_pass for `test.example.com`, but I still don't get what service you want to expose, if example you have php in port 1080, then `192.168.56.147:1080` , and from your windows use `test.example.com:1025`, becaue the proxy listen on port 1025 based on your podman port map

Comment: I don't want `:1025` but only `test.example.com` as if it works on a real server with a real domain name.

Comment: If you want real server, change the nginx proxy run... on podman to port 80... `podman run -dt -p 80:80 -p 81:81 -p 443:443 # rest command ommited`, and you need to run it as root.. or allow your user to use lower port as unprivileged user... You need to learn container more tbh..

Comment: Are you sure. I tried running as root using docker same problem using the port. Additional options I used other than what you gave was `--name`, `-v` and `--restart`. Actually I used docker-compose following the original documentation of nginxproxymanager.

Comment: yes... I'm sure, I have one on production for it, and you should know, the port map is `-p <host port>:<container-port>`. The port should work as it's... With your docs/question, the port should be mapped to 80, so when you use the server IP (192.168.56.147), you will directly go to port 80, and port 80 will be map to nginx proxy manager at port 80.. and don't forget to add `192.168.56.147 test.example.com` on windows hosts file... I urge you to learn the container map concept.. it won't be that hard after your understand the concept, to look into my comment.

Comment: Thanks this did work. If can post it as an Answer. So I can close this question. And also if you are aware of any good online resource to learn container map concept. Please consider sharing it with me. A great help.