# DNS Server Emulation using a local test domain name for VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns, proxy, dnsmasq

I see nginxreverseproxy does not work in Virtualbox as if it will work on a Server. Check this [Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1788864/setup-a-reverse-proxy-for-a-debian-virtualbox?noredirect=1#comment2799014_1788864). Based on my research I see dns servers are important to manage domain names. So I think if I am able to emulate a local DNS Server with a test domain such as `example.com`. It will be a great way to test out things. I even intend to run SMTP email servers to test and learn. So I think this will be very helpful. So that I can configure records such `mx`. And also I can get fake ssl certificates for these tests.

Is it possible to achieve such a setup. Just to test and learn, I don't need to rent a dedicated vps or domain right.

Thanks in Advance. This will be a great help.

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: @JaromandaX Good to hear. Will you be able to give the complete answer on how to set it up. Note: My Host is Windows

Comment: not easy in windows.

Comment: . I prefer to have this setup between Windows Host to Linux VirtualBox. If it is impossible or very difficult, I thought of another workaround setting this up  for VirtualBox Linux Server within VirtualBox Linux Desktop as Host running on a Windows Host. If you think this is a good idea. Can you show what the process could be.